deploying node.js gulp project in cloud run
I'm try to deploy node.js project with gulp in cloud run, after the deployment I'm not able to run the application, i get this message in the logs:
`[06:44:21] Finished 'scssTask' after 11 s`
`[06:44:21] Finished 'htmlTask' after 12 s`
`[06:45:42] gulp-imagemin: Minified 95 images (saved 5.12 MB - 23.9%)`
`[06:45:42] Finished 'imgTask' after 1.53 min`
`[06:45:42] Starting 'browsersyncServe'...`
`[06:45:42] Finished 'browsersyncServe' after 10 ms`
`[06:45:42] Starting 'watchTask'...`
`[Browsersync] Access URLs:`
` ----------------------------------`
`      Local: http://localhost:3000`
`   External: http://10.1.0.51:3000`
` ----------------------------------`
`          UI: http://localhost:3001`
` UI External: http://localhost:3001`
` ----------------------------------`
`[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./build`
`[Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)`

below is the package.json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp",
    "prod": "gulp prod"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.1",
    "cssnano": "^6.0.0",
    "del": "6.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "7.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-pretty-html": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-purgecss": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "sass": "^1.60.0"
  }
}

in local I'm able run the application, but in gcp I'm not

I'm unfamiliar with gulp and I'm unsure about the output e.g. http://localhost:3000 and http:/10.1.0.51:3000. Cloud Run very specifically requires a service to listen for connections on a port (defaulting to 8080). gulp doesn't appear to meet  this requirement. I'm unsure whether those URLs are being accessed or serviced but they're both incorrect (localhost won't be published beyond the container and 10.x.x.x is a private IP address). If your deployment is a web server, please update your question indicating this.

If it is a job that does something and completes, you may want to use Cloud Run jobs instead.
